# Rewrite URL's with SVN

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, redirect

I currently have several svn repo's set up for use by a small collection of people.
They currently access there repo by the following url pattern:
https://svn.example.com/svn/project
If they have multiple packages (which some, but not all do) its:
https://svn.example.com/svn/project/packageA and so on.

I would like to remove the /svn/ out of the url. I have tried using RewriteRule and RedirectMatch in apache with no success.

This is the virtual host file, prior to trying to change the URL:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerAdmin admin@example.com
  ServerName www.svn.example.com
  ServerAlias svn.example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/svn

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.pem
  SSLProtocol all
  SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM

  <Location /var/svn/>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /var/svn
    SVNListParentPath on
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Subversion Repository"
    AuthUserFile /var/svn/svn-auth-file
    Require valid-user

  </Location>
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

  LogLevel warn

  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
  ServerSignature On

  </VirtualHost>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

**Preface**

1. Your *written* config doesn't reflect your *described* config: `/svn` path vs `/var/svn/` location
2. You config must not work at all (or work with **big troubles**): DocumentRoot == Location == SVNParentPath, because they are a) unrelated b) different parameters

When you want to change path to your repos, you have to rewrite only definition of SVN-location, it can be / in your case (and beware: non-WebDAV tree under root will have problems in this case, if all site is repositories only it's OK for root-location)

`<Location />` is short answer on your question

Answer (score 1):

**Assumption**
You have two svn repositories located at:

1. /var/svn/repo1
2. /var/svn/repo2

And so URLs would be:

1. http://svn.example.com/repo1/project1/PackageA
2. http://svn.example.com/repo2/project1/PackageA

**Requirement**
To access `PackageA` of `Project1` of `repo1` using URL:

```
http://svn.example.com/project1/PackageA
```

**Probable Solution**

```
-<Location /var/svn/>
+<Location />
     DAV svn
    -SVNParentPath /var/svn
    +SVNPath /var/svn/repo1
    -SVNListParentPath on
     AuthType Basic
     AuthName "Subversion Repository"
     AuthUserFile /var/svn/svn-auth-file
     Require valid-user    
 </Location>
```

And, restart httpd.